# Salesforce - Access Tax Exemption Certificates stored in Salesforce

Tags: data

Can anyone provide some insight on how to access tax exception certificates that are stored in Salesforce?

Is there a way to obtain a certificate a customer has uploaded? 
Is there a way to extract all the certificate/forms customers uploaded?

Does Salesforce store sales tax exemption certificate information such as the certificate ID, tax exempt status, certificate type etc?

Thanks for all of your time in advance. 
Any insight will help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of places you can store files in the core Salesforce functionality. But there is no standard place that it is stored. If you need the actual file, the natural place I would look for that is as an attachment for a record. If just the certificate ID, expiry date, and other details, you could just store that in a few custom fields.

All of this can be done with some minor customizations. Although attachments are a default feature of any object.

Alternatively, if there is a global database to lookup or verify this information, it wouldn't be difficult for a developer to write some functionality to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This really helps. Would you by any chance also know if I can download all attachments for a record at once?

Comment: Not certain...my first instinct is maybe not, and I do not currently have access to docs. But this is worth its own question, IMO. Or search to see if someone has already asked.